# PHP/mysql real_escape and special characters

Tags: php, mysql, insert, special-characters

To prevent SQL injection attacks prior to doing queries (including INSERT ones) I am using `mysql_real_escape_string`.

The problem is that if the data to be entered has a special character in it, MySQL seems to insert the slash into the database on insert.

Then, when I display the field on a webpage, the slash appears.

Ideally, I do not want to have slashes before special characters in the dbase tables as this will require a lot of ongoing maintenance to remove slashes when displaying the data etc.

Is there anyway to store in the database without including the backslash?

As an example:

```
$field = "bob's data";
...establish database connection
$field = mysql_real_escape_string($field);
$sql="INSERT INTO table (field) VALUES ('$field')";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
{
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

This code stores "bob's data" in the database.

Is there anyway to handle this differently so as not to end up with slashes in the database?

Note: I know the preferred way to do queries is to use parameterized queries or pdo but for various reasons, cannot do that in this instance as it is huge legacy website.

Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Google for `magic_quotes`

Comment: Did you really assign `$field` literally like that, or did it come from `$_GET` or `$_POST`? If it came from client input, `magic_quotes` could be the problem, as @zerkms mentions. If it's literal, I don't believe it's happening as you say.

Comment: It came from a post from a textarea.  I just wrote it that way in question to illustrate case where the input has an apostrophe.  I don't think magic quotes is on.

Comment: Magic quotes (or a double-escaping) is the only sensible explanation for this

Comment: You are right. I can't believe it.  I tested for magic quotes and they are on.  This is a cloud hosted site.  Where would I turn them off?

Comment: Could you use stripslashes function before it goes into the database?

Comment: @Nick That is a massive nono

Comment: @user1904273 Do you have access to php.ini? and the user rights to restart apache..?

Comment: @DarylGill Yes, I understand. If you read his post they don't want slashes in the database.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use something like this before processing any GET, POST, COOKIE or REQUEST object.

```
function removeMagiQuotes()
{
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $process = array(&$_GET, &$_POST, &$_COOKIE, &$_REQUEST);
    while (list($key, $val) = each($process)) {
        foreach ($val as $k => $v) {
            unset($process[$key][$k]);
            if (is_array($v)) {
                $process[$key][stripslashes($k)] = $v;
                $process[] = &$process[$key][stripslashes($k)];
            } else {
                $process[$key][stripslashes($k)] = stripslashes($v);
            }
        }
    }
    unset($process);
}
}
```